Relaxed form of the graph isomorphism problem?
Let $G_1=(L_1,R_1,E_1)$ and $G_2=(L_2,R_2,E_2)$ be bipartite directed graphs and let $\lambda:L_1\to L_2$ be a bijection between the $L$ vertex sets of the graphs. If I wanted to determine whether $G_1$ and $G_2$ are isomorphic, would knowing $\lambda$ help me do it more efficiently than if I didn't know $\lambda$?, or the time complexity remains that of the graph isomorphism problem?
My guess is that it depends on the size of $R_1$ and $R_2$ (for example, suppose $n:=|L_1|$ and $|R_1|=\log n$), but I'm not sure about it.

Knowing $\lambda$ definitely helps. Using this mapping, we can order the vertices in $R_1$ and $R_2$ and then perform a linear scan to verify the isomorphism. This should not take more than $O(n\log n)$ time.
First, fix any order of the vertices in $L_1$. Using this, we can now order the vertices of $R_1$ as follows: Consider two vertices $b_1,b_2 \in R_1$, which connect to say $(a_1, a_3, a_{10})$ and $(a_1, a_5)$. We now impose a lexicography order, i.e. $(a_1, a_3, a_{10}) < (a_1, a_5)$, and say $b_1 < b_2$
